# What is the difference between interfaces with function properties like "f()" and "f: () =>"?

Tags: typescript

Consider next A and B interfaces:

```
interface A {f(): number}
interface B {f: () => number}
```

I've tried next things:

```
var a: A = {f: function() {return 1}}
var a: A = {f: () => 1}
var b: B = {f: function() {return 1}}
var b: B = {f: () => 1}
```

Looks like the same.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. They are just two different notations. Your interfaces say that there must be a property `f`, which is a function with no parameters returning a number.

`{f: function() {return 1}}` and `{f: () => 1}` are two ways to implement this interface. The only difference is that the second one makes use of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). This is mostly syntatic sugar, but differs slightly by the use of the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
interface A { f(): number }
```

Is the notation for declaring a method, and this:

```
interface B { f: () => number }
```

Is how to declare a property of a function type.

While there's no real difference when it comes to interfaces it makes more sense in a class:

```
class MyClass {
    fn1() {
        return 0;
    }

    fn2 = () => {
        return 0;
    }

    fn3 = function () {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.fn2 = function () {
            return 0;
        };
        this.fn3 = function () {
            return 0;
        };
    }
    MyClass.prototype.fn1 = function () {
        return 0;
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

As you can see only `fn1` is a method attached to the prototype, while the other two are just properties (assigned in the constructor).